# Hyperledger: Error: cannot create ledger from genesis block: ledger [mychannel] already exists with state [ACTIVE]

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I'm trying to add an organisation to a channel following the documentation [tutorial](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/channel_update_tutorial.html). Everything goes all right but the last command, the one to join the new organisation to the channel.

```
peer channel join -b channel-artifacts/channel1.block
```

I've read that this indicates that the peers have already joined the channel, but that's not the case. When I try to deploy a contract, for example, it can't be installed on the peers of the new organisation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that some docker volumes were kept after restarting the network. So I shut down the network and ran the following command to delete the all docker volumes in the system.

`docker system prune --volumes -f`

After restarting, the organisation could be joined to the networks without errors.

Comment: Your answer is right. I have commented out a few lines of code in the network.sh file, which will remove the volumes. I have a doubt: does CouchDB data persist on volumes? Currently, my code is not persisting data, so I have commented those lines. Now, I am facing this error when I try to run the command. Can you tell me how to persist data?